# How to resolve java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 43, Size: 36 in Android recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**I am getting below error on scrolling very fast on recyclerview. It doesn't occur if I scroll slow.**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.freshop.android.adhoc.consumer, PID: 12225
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 43, Size: 36
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.freshop.android.consumer.adapter.DepartmentsAdapter$CustomViewHolder$1.onScrollStateChanged(DepartmentsAdapter.java:526)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView.java:5210)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setScrollState(RecyclerView.java:1550)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5397)
```

Here is code snippet of DepartmentsAdapter.

```
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView departmentTitle;
        private final TextView moreProducts;
        private final RecyclerView mHorizontalRecyclerView;
        private ProductShowcaseAdapter showcaseAdapter;
        private final ProgressBar progress;
        private final FrameLayout item_framelayout;
        private final LinearLayout pr_row;

        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            pr_row = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pr_row);
            departmentTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.department);
            moreProducts = itemView.findViewById(R.id.moreProducts);
            progress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            item_framelayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            mHorizontalRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_collection_row);
        }

        public void bind(final CustomViewHolder holder,
                         final Department department,
                         final int position, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            Log.d(TAG,"bind");
            if (department == null) { return; }
            if (department.getDepartmentProducts() != null && department.getDepartmentProducts().size() > 0) {
                holder.departmentTitle.setText(department.getName());
                if (!department.getHasViewMore()) {
                    holder.moreProducts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.moreProducts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.moreProducts.setText(R.string.lbl_more);
                    holder.moreProducts.setContentDescription(department.getName() + context.get().getString(R.string.lbl_more));
                    holder.moreProducts.setTextColor(Theme.primaryColor);
                    holder.moreProducts.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                        if(fragment != null) {
                            (((ProductShowcaseFragment)fragment)).updateDataScrollToTopListener();
                        }
                        listener.onItemClick(null, department, AppConstants.PRODUCTBTNTYPEMORE, null, null, 0, 0);
                    });
                }

                List<Product> products1 = DataHelper.updateProductsWithFavAndListItems(department.getDepartmentProducts(), shoppingListItems);

                if (showcaseAdapter == null && context != null) {
                    //Log.d(TAG,"showcaseAdapter == null");
                    showcaseAdapter = new ProductShowcaseAdapter(context.get(), imageConfig, products1, shoppingListItems,
                            (data, product, holder1, type, pos) -> listener.onItemClick(product, department, type, holder1, data, position, pos),
                            DataHelper::trackUrlOnLoad);

                    mHorizontalRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                    ((SimpleItemAnimator) Objects.requireNonNull(mHorizontalRecyclerView.getItemAnimator())).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

                    if (context != null) {
                        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context.get());
                        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
                        mHorizontalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
                    }
                    mHorizontalRecyclerView.setAdapter(holder.showcaseAdapter);
                } else {
                    //Log.d(TAG,"showcaseAdapter != null");
                    if (showcaseAdapter != null)
                        showcaseAdapter.updateDataSet(products1, shoppingListItems);
                }

                holder.item_framelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (products1 != null && products1.size() >= Integer.parseInt(department.getLimit())) {
                    mHorizontalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                            //Log.d(TAG,"onScrollStateChanged");

                            if (!recyclerView.canScrollHorizontally(1) && !mScrolled) {
                                if (scrollListener != null) {
                                    //Log.d(TAG,"scrollListener");
                                    scrollListener.onScrollListener(true, department, position);
                                }
                            }
                            if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null &&
                                    department.getDepartmentProducts().size() > 0 &&
                                    ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() >= 0) {
                                if (department.getDepartmentProducts().contains(department.getDepartmentProducts()
```

**//Line 526 from stacktrace points here**

```
    .get(((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()))) {
DataHelper.trackUrlOnView(department.getDepartmentProducts().get(((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
```

here is DataHelper.trackUrlOnView

```
public static void trackUrlOnView(Product product) {
        Log.d(TAG,"trackUrlOnView");
        if (product == null) return;

        if (DataHelper.isNullOrEmpty(product.getOnViewProductUrl())) return;

        if (product.getIsAd() && !product.isHasViewedAd()
                && !DataHelper.isNullOrEmpty(product.getOnViewProductUrl())) {
            final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(product.getOnViewProductUrl())
                    .build();

            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                    product.setHasViewedAd(true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you need anymore details. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

err this line code:
at com.freshop.android.consumer.adapter.DepartmentsAdapter$CustomViewHolder$1.onScrollStateChanged(DepartmentsAdapter.java:526)

write your DepartmentsAdapter class,see.....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).